# Trouble positioning elements within a custom css grid

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a Magento store using the Ultimo theme from Theme Forest and am trying to customise the homepage so that it matches the design I have been given.

Ultimo uses a custom grid system i.e. grid12-1, grid12-2, grid12-3 etc,etc.
I'm trying to position 3 blocks where the first column has 2 rows and the second column has just 1.

Example can be found here http://www.lifestylemedicine.co.uk/

I can't get the blocks to line up correctly and would appreciate some help. At the moment the first 2 blocks are positioned correctly but the 2nd column has dropped down.

I think it might be a a div in the wrong place or something stupid anyway.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Here is my code

```
<div class="welcome-box">

<div class="grid12-8 mobile-grid welcome-intro">
<div class="intro-caption">“I’m delighted to welcome you to the new Nina      Torina® clinical website and online store; this is the evolution of what many of you have known as FixbyOsteo® and incorporates my individual and corporate coaching practice, as well as the Aesthetic Skin Health clinics.”
<br /><br />
<span class="signature">Nina Victoria Gallagher</span><br />FOUNDER</div>
</div></div>
<div class="grid12-8 mobile-grid">
<div class="home-social">
<div class="heading">keep in touch and join in with us</div><br />
icons here
</div>
</div>
<div class="grid12-4 mobile-grid treatments">
<div class="intro-caption-treatments">
<div class="heading">New<br />Treatments</div>
<span class="signature">from the</span><br />CLINIC</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your css code ?

Comment: It seems like its same as `bootstrap` means you've to make count of `12` for a single `row` i.e.  `grid12-8` and `grid12-4` will be on same line as they make `12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to be doing.

[image]

You basically just have to move a few thing around here and add the appropriate grid class to the parent. Sure you will get the idea by looking at the above image.

Here is what this will look like in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks David. That is perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes to your Welcome Image. to 12grid
Here[image]

Comment: make class="grid12-12"

Comment: But that isn't what I want. The first image should be grid12-8 with the next image grid12-4 with another grid12-8 underneath the 1st.

Comment: IF you don't want welcome image to be 12grid you have to make 8 and 4 grid div and within 8 grid place your image and below content and in 4 grid  put new treatments. This will work

Comment: welcome-box div and grid12-8 mobile-grid welcome-intro closing shift after  grid12-8 mobile-grid . This will helo.

Comment: What is a "closing shift"?

Comment: Close these divs after  grid12-8 mobile-grid

Comment: This pushes the 2nd row up on top of the 1st image.

Comment: Show me the screenshot.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of, or in addition to, screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the [edit] link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This screenshot may help you :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of, or in addition to, screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the [edit] link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you . LEt me know any help

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of, or in addition to, screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the [edit] link under the post. Thank you.